# React Native - SQLite Can not find pre-populated database file

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to use https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage for SQLite.

I made a sqlite database and it is pre-populated.

On my react-native project, I put `players.db` file to `/www` folder as documentation says.

But when I inspect from console opening database is failing. **I can not open my pre-populated sqlite database.**

I tried these options and all of them not working for me;

```
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db", createFromLocation : "~players.db"});

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db", createFromLocation :1});

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players", createFromLocation : "~players.db"});
```

And console output is:

```
OPEN database: players
Running application "SampleApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":31}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
new transaction is waiting for open operation
OPEN database: players failed, aborting any pending transactions
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @TejasPatel i found answer myself. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

`ProjectFolder/android/app/src/main/assets` directory is same to /www folder. So don't put your database file to `/www`. Put it to `/android/app/src/main/assets` folder.

Then you can use it like

```
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db", createFromLocation : "~players.db"});
```

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Comment: That does not work for me :(. So sad

Answer (score 4):

In Android, place your database file in 'PROJECT\android\app\src\main\assets' directory. If your database filename is different (say, players.db VS example.db) then,

1. Its location should be: PROJECT\android\app\src\main\assets\example.db
2. Import using:

```js
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db", createFromLocation : "~example.db", location: 'Library'});
```

If your filename is same as the database (both named players.db) then

1. Its location should be: PROJECT\android\app\src\main\assets\players.db
2. Import using:

```js
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db", createFromLocation : "~players.db", location: 'Library'});
```

If you have already messed up with importing a pre-populated database, try clearing up the application data from the emulator/mobile phone and/or uninstalling the app completely before following the steps above.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using defaults then, try:

`var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "players.db"});`

this should work.

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?