# Reading .sdf file (SQL Server Compact File) in reactnative

Tags: react-native, sql-server-ce

I am trying to open a `.sdf` SQL Server Compact database file directly into my React application. How can I open it in React Native directly, without any server or need of an API?

I am building an app that will use the scrapped data stored into a database file and based on that generate a timetable. I do have the app built on C# but it's someone's else code and it works on Windows only. It has a separate scrapper that generates C# file. Now, I don't want to redo scrapping all over again.

Basically, I want a React native mobile app that maybe asks to download database file from the internet (my custom url later on like drive link etc) if it's not already there or needs updating and then I am able to read that directly into my react-native application.

Can I do that? There is no clear tutorial of this so far in my searching. I don't want API nor any server extras. Thank you

Comment: you need to have SQL Server Compact to work with the data in the file

Comment: Side note: SQL Server Compact is way out of support. Consider upgrading to SQL Server Express or LocalDB 2022

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why people are disliking my post that's strange.
Anyway, I found the answer to the question and that was to convert the **.sdf** *(SQL Server Compact)* database into **SQL-Lite database file** using [.sdf to .sqlite converter](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-sqlce-to-sqlite-onlines)

And then in the app, following the answer of **hakkikonu** from [SQLITE database Connection in ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647109/react-native-sqlite-can-not-find-pre-populated-database-file?rq=3). Put my converted **.sqlite** file into the assets folder,  changed it's **extension** to **.db** and used that given code to connect and voila it worked.
After that, you can use SQLITE documentation to play around with the data.

Also you can use this amazing tool to browse your SQL-Lite database file as well. [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)